# Is it possible to create web app and deploy it on the app store?

Tags: ios, web

Sorry for the question if it makes no sense, I'm pretty new to all this but I have been approached by a client to build a website and build an ios app for his product. The website and app is an ecommerce site. My question is, is it possible for me to go and create a web site using the likes of Ruby on rails, node.js or php which then can be deployed on the app store? if it ain't possible I am open to teaching myself ios10.

I haven't committed to this job yet as I informed him of my level of experience and I want to do my research before accepting.

Whats your suggestions?
Kind Regards,
Johnathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following excerpt from the App Store Review Guidelines:

> **4.2 Minimum Functionality**
>   Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website.
> …

So no, you wouldn't be able to do it like that.

Comment: So if I was to add features, content and UI to the website I should be able to deploy it on the app store? or did I just get confused as to what you said? any suggestions how I should go about my problem?

Comment: No, it has to have app-like features and behavior beyond what you'd typically see in a website.    You know, you could always write an app UI using HTML and CSS and all that.  The important part is that it has to feel like an app.  If it feels more like a website than an app, then it's a problem.

Comment: I get you now! Thank you for taking your time to help me!